# How can I list files by class/indicator (as in ls --classify) then by name?

Tags: shell-script, find, ls, sort

`ls --clasify` append indicator (one of `*/=>@|`) to entries. I would like to group the entries of the same class/indicator together.

I can only find `ls --group-directories-first` for grouping the `/` together, **how can I group executables `*`, symlinks `@`, pipes `|` and sockets `=`, too?**

`ls` is *not* required, any dirty-hack is welcomed. But as for the output style, I would like a multi-columned colored output with indicator, similar to what `ls -C --color -F` did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If dirty hacks are welcomed, the following might come close:

```
ls -C --color -F -1 | rev | sort | rev
```

Essentially:

- `rev` to get the last character first
- then `sort`, which will now use the last character first
- then `rev` again to get back the original line

This, unfortunately, has single-column output. You can apply `column` to it to get multi-column output, but because of the non-printing characters, the columns get messed up:

```
$ ls -C --color -F /proc/self/ -1 | rev | sort -i | rev | column -x
fd/     task/       fdinfo/ attr/   ns/     net/        cwd@
exe@        root@       sched           cmdline         oom_score       oom_score_adj       oom_adj
stack           syscall         mem         comm            statm           wchan           environ
mountinfo       io          pagemap         cgroup          autogroup       coredump_filter     clear_refs
maps            numa_maps       smaps           mountstats      limits          mounts          status
stat            schedstat       cpuset          auxv            personality
```

And, of course, it assumes caveats:

- no newlines in the filenames
- none of the `ls` marking characters are in the filenames

---

A bash function, using a combination of `find`, `sort` and `ls` itself that comes close:

```bsh
lsc () (
    [[ -z $1 ]] && set .
    for path
    do
        [[ -d $path ]] || { ls -CF --color "$path"; echo; continue; }
        (( $#  > 1 )) && printf '%s:\n' "$path" 
        find "$path" -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 ! -iname '.*' -printf "%y %p\0" |
        while IFS= read -d '' -r entry
        do
            ftype="${entry:0:1}"
            fname="${entry:2}"
            [[ $ftype == f && -x $fname ]] && ftype=x
            printf "$ftype $fname\0"
        done | sort -z -k1 | 
        sed -z 's/^. //; s:.*/::' |
        xargs -0 bash -c 'cd "$0"; ls -CFUd --color "$@"' "$path"
        (( $#  > 1 )) && echo
    done
)
```

By using `ls` itself, printing to multiple columns becomes much easier.

Answer (score 2):

Using the same `ls -CFUd` as *muru* but in `zsh`, you could try with:

```
(set -o nullglob; ls --color -CFUd -- *(/) *(*) *(@) *(p) *(=) *(^/*@p=))
```

where `(...)` are [glob-qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) matching directories, executables, symlinks, pipes, sockets and respectively everything else.

You could also define a `bytype` sorting function as:

```
zmodload -F zsh/stat b:zstat
bytype() {
  local mode order=(d l p s b c)
  zstat -sLA mode +mode -- $REPLY
  REPLY=$order[(ie)${mode[1][1]}]$REPLY
}
```

```
ls --color -CFUd -- *(o+bytype)
```

That will sort based on the first character of the text representation of the mode (the first field in `ls -l` output), so `-` for regular files, `l` for symlinks, etc, looked up for ranking in the `$order` array.

Note that executables are not a type of file and are not treated specially there. For `ls -F`, or the `*` glob qualifier, an executable file is a *regular* file that has at least one execution bit set in its permissions (regardless of whether *you* have execution permission yourself), so you could handle them with:

```
zmodload -F zsh/stat b:zstat
bytype() {
  local mode order=(d '*' l p s b c)
  zstat -sLA mode +mode -- $REPLY
  if [[ $mode = -*[xts]* ]] mode=('*')
  REPLY=$order[(ie)${mode[1][1]}]$REPLY
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
l='ls -F --color'  
paste -d: <($l | grep '/$') <($l | grep '*$') <($l | grep '@$') <($l | grep -v '[/@*]$') |
tac| column -t -s ":" -N FOLDERS,EXECUTABLES,LINKS,OTHER
```

[image]